# ASP.NET MVC 5: Make a select required based on the selected option of another select

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 selects generated (TipoVinculo and CboId) and I need the select CboId to be required if the selected option of the TipoVinculo is not "Estagiario".

**Plus:**
If the option selected in TipoVinculo is "Estagiario" the select CboId should disappear

Code below:

**View**

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoVinculo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "required control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.TipoVinculo, "-- Selecione --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoVinculo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CboId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "required control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select id="CboId" name="CboId" class="form-control"></select>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CboId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**ViewModel**

```
    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Vínculo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O {0} é obrigatório")]
    public TipoVinculo? TipoVinculo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Classificação Brasileira de Ocupação")]
    public string CboId { get; set; }
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="required control-label col-md-2" for="TipoVinculo">Tipo de Vínculo</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="O Tipo de Vínculo é obrigatório" id="TipoVinculo" name="TipoVinculo">
            <option selected="selected" value="">-- Selecione --</option>
            <option value="1">Contratado</option>
            <option value="2">Estatutario</option>
            <option value="3">Comissionado</option>
            <option value="4">Estagiario</option>
        </select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="TipoVinculo" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="required control-label col-md-2" for="CboId">Classificação Brasileira de Ocupação</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select id="CboId" name="CboId" class="form-control">
            <option value="">-- Selecione --</option>
            <option value="1">...</option>
            <option value="2">...</option>
            ...
        </select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CboId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using jQuery Validation but I did not succeed

```
$('#frm-add-sol').validate({
    rules: {
        CboId: {
            depends: function (element) {
                return $("#TipoVinculo").val() != "4";
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        CboId: "Classificação Brasileira de Ocupação é obrigatorio"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
if ($('#TipoVinculo option:selected').val() == 'Estagiario') {
        // Apply Required Validation
        $('[name="CboId"]').rules('add', {
            required: true, messages: {
                required: "Cbo is required."
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        // Remove Required Validation
        $('input[name="SubBranchId"]').rules('remove', 'required');
    }
```

You need to write above code in dropdown `"TipoVinculo"` on change event.